# SWT/JFace Tooltip for Text Control when text in control is too large to be displayed

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I know this can be implemented fairly easily but I must use a standard functionality for this.
I need a tooltip to be shown on a text field but only when the text in the text field is to long to be displayed in the field. Tables and Tree's have this functionality when resizeing columns but I didn't find anything similar for text fields.

I didn't manage to find this functionality in Eclipse either so I'm guessing it's not a standard functionality.
Please prove me wrong:).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does it mean "Standard functionality"..? Adding `modifyListener` to `Text` instance is (imo) standard fair enough.

Here's my approach

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.ModifyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;


public class TextLabel {
    public TextLabel() {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        shell.setSize(200, 150);
        shell.setText("Long Text content label");

        Text txtLong = new Text(shell, SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);
        txtLong.addModifyListener(new ModifyListener() {

            @Override
            public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                Text txtSource = (Text) e.getSource();
                Point size = (new GC(txtSource)).stringExtent(txtSource.getText());
                if(size.x > txtSource.getBounds().width - txtSource.getBorderWidth()) txtSource.setToolTipText(txtSource.getText());
                else txtSource.setToolTipText(null);
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TextLabel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, standard functionality means out of the box, exactly like it is by tables and trees. I tought maybe it's implemented out of the box and I''l just have to activate it or something.However your code is corect and is working.

Comment: Basically, if you build a table or a tree, resize one column so the text doesn't fit anymore, you'll see that the components offer this functionality out of the box.

Comment: You could be right, I only have windows so I can't verify that.